# How to dynamic transport values for sorting?

Tags: node.js, express, knex.js

Currently, knex has generated the following query:

```
select * from (select "NAME" from "USERS" order by "NAME" asc) where rownum <= 10
```

How can I make it so that instead of the `order by "NAME" asc` column the value that I select on the client for sorting is sent?

Using knex i sort so:

```
.orderBy('NAME', req.query.order)
```

What needs to be done so that the `NAME` column changes depending on the transmitted column on the client to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass a client variable instead of the `'NAME'` value.

```
.orderBy(req.query.colName, req.query.order);
```